# How can I insert an html-template file into postgresql field from command line

Tags: bash, postgresql, makefile, psql

I have a html-template in a postgresql table, which I need to fetch and update from cmdline.

My idea was to use a Makefile to update the field.

I have figured, that I can use this command to fetch the file, using a function in a Makefile.

```sh
psql_conn=psql -U ${pg_user} -p $(pg_port_staging) -h $(pg_host) -d $(pg_database)
psql_shell=--tuples-only -P format=unaligned

fetch: ## fetch a given template id=XX
ifndef id
    @echo "Missing id=XX"
    @$(MAKE) list
    @exit 1
else
    $(call fetch_template,$(id),$(call fetch_name,$(id)))
endif

define fetch_template
    $(shell echo "SELECT template FROM pdf_templates WHERE id = $(1)" | ${psql_conn} $(psql_shell} > $(2).html)
endef

define fetch_name
  ...
endef
```

However, I have a problem with inserting this template into the table again, after editing.

An example template file could be like this, so it would containts `+ { $` and UTF8 charaters.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <style type="text/css" th:inline="text">
        body { margin: 0; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; }
        a { text-decoration: none; }
</style>
</head
<body>
<div th:if="${hasAddresses}">
            <h2>Adresser:</h2>
            <article th:each="offerElement: ${offer.getElementsWithData().?[specification?.get('elementType') == 'fiber']}">
                <div th:with="address=${offerElement.getParsedData().get()}">
                    <br /><span th:text="${address['deliveryStreet']}"></span> <span th:text="${address['deliveryHouseNumber']}"></span>
                    <span th:text="${address['deliveryFloor']}"></span> <span th:text="${address['deliveryDoor']}"></span>
                    <br /><span th:text="${address['deliveryZipCode']}"></span> <span th:text="${address['deliveryCity']}"></span>
                    <br /><span th:text="${address['deliveryCountry']}"></span>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's a remote server, I don't have shell access to. So it's not an option to use `pg_read_file`

I have worked with the idea with using `\lo_import File.html` which upload the file to the server, but can't figure out how the content can be written into the table, and not just appear in the LargeObject table.

Another solution might be to use Ruby or Python, but I want to keep it as simple as possible.

The psql version i 9.4 however the server is running postgresql server 10.4.

Comment: Please, post a sample html template and the desired updates.

Comment: I have added a HTML template file, however it just look like a normal html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution by converting the content to base64

```
define write_template
$(shell echo "UPDATE table SET template = convert_from(decode('$(shell base64 $(1))', 'base64'),'UTF8') WHERE name = '$(2)'" | ${psql_input})
endef
```

So take the content from `base64 filename.html` and use `convert_from( decode($content , 'base64'),'UTF8')` functions in postgresql to first decode the content to bytestring and thereafter convert it to UTF-8 format.

The `${psql_input}` is just `psql` with user/host parameters.